# BigQuery standard SQL syntax: _TABLE_SUFFIX and .yesterday tables

Tags: google-bigquery

My goal is to query across multiple tables of a dataset using BigQuery standard SQL syntax.

I can successfully make it work when all tables of a dataset follow the same number pattern. However, for datasets that contain additional tables like `.yesterday`, I get an error: `Views cannot be queried through prefix. Matched views are: githubarchive:day.yesterday`

Here is the query I used:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `githubarchive.day.*`
WHERE
  type = "WatchEvent"
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170215'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using more of a prefix. For example,

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `githubarchive.day.2017*`
WHERE
  type = "WatchEvent"
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0101' AND '0215';
```

Comment: Hey Elliott can you explain this including why OP's query does not work?

Comment: The OP's prefix matched some views (hence the error message), but using a longer prefix caused the query not to match them.